# How can to get Excel to stop calculating a formula once Data shows up on Separate Column

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

[image: if you look at the image, what i am trying to accomplish is having H column formula stop computing and go blank once I input a date on I column]

I am currently trying to show the amount of days an item in my inventory is on the market for. This is the current formula I am using for that:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",TODAY()-[@[Date Precured]])
```

Once the item sells I input the date sold into a separate column and I would like for Excel to stop calculating the previous formula once that information is inputted.

What do I need to add to my current formula for that to happen?

Comment: Hi @KINGYO1988,, could U plzz write that the shown formula in in which cell and where (cell) you are entering the Sale data,, and would U hopefully like to stop calculating this `=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",TODAY()-[@[Date Precured]])`,,, or for better understanding share some screen shot with us.

Comment: I just attached a screenshot if that helps. I'm new to this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi  KINGYO1988,, `=IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(I2)),NOT(ISTEXT(I2))),"",TODAY()-F2))`,, this will check IF U enter DATE in I2 ,, return BLANK,, and if enter either TEXT or is BLANK then use TODAY()-F2, But in case if U write NUMBER, then Excel will convert it into DATE ,, since one DATE written in cell, EXCEL converts NUMBER into DATE,,, hope this work for U.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the formula reference its own cell and use this (suppose this is in column G):

```
=IF(G2="",IF(ISBLANK(F2),"",TODAY()-[@[Date Precured]]),G2)
```

This will of course cause a circular reference error, so you must also turn on iterative calculation using File>Options>Formulas>Calculation Options>Enable Iterative Calculation:

[image]

Please read this to understand the implications of using that option:
[Remove Or Allow a Circular Reference - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123)

Comment: Hi there! I tried this but it doesn't work and I cannot find the option you suggested. I did attach a screenshot if that helps. Thank you!